# Chromatic number $\chi(G)=600$, $P(\chi(G|_S)\leq 200) \leq 2^{-10}$

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, martingales, coloring

I am learning martingale and Hoeffding-Azuma inequality recently but do not how to apply the those inequality or theorem here.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with chromatic number 600,i.e. $\chi(G)=600$. Let $S$ be a random subset uniformly chosen from $V$. Denote $G|_S$ the induced subgraph of $G$ on $S$. Prove that 
$$P(\chi(G|_S)\leq 200 )\leq 2^{-10}.$$

I am not sure how to approach ones, especially for the condition $\chi(G)=600$. I am thinking that for a 600 vertices complete graph, the probability to be computed is just the ratio $$\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{200}C_i^{600} }{2^{600}},$$

meaning the ratio btween the number of all subgraph with vertices number less than 200 and the total number of subset of $V$. But is it enough?  Even this ratio is hard to compute.

Comment: Do you really mean the **coloring** number? The notation $\chi(G)$ is normally used for the **chromatic** number of a graph. In general, the coloring number is greater than the chromatic number.,

Comment: @bof, oh,  I do not know the difference between the two indeed. I thought the two are the same (as my prof only talked about coloring number). I mean the minimum number so that each adjacent vertices have different colors.

Comment: The "coloring number" of a graph is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#Definitions_and_equivalences). For greater clarity, I recommend that you change "coloring number" to "chromatic number".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. If you choose a set at random, then with probability at least 1/2 the chromatic number is at least 300 (why?).
2. Azuma's inequality shows that the chromatic number of $G|_S$ is concentrated around its mean.
3. Since the chromatic number is always between 0 and 600, and its median is above 300, its mean can't be too low.
4. Hence the probability that the chromatic number of $G|_S$ is as low as 200 is small.

Comment: I still don't quite get it, can you explain more to me ( I have been struggling for some time....)? For 1, I was thinking about vertices and not sure how to connect these to the chromatic number. When I need to use the Azuma's inequality, should I use the filtration $\mathcal{F}_n$ which is  all the subsets  of the first $n$ vertices?

Comment: For 1, see what you can say about the chromatic number of $G|_S$ and $G|_{S^c}$. You can indeed apply Azuma's inequality with respect to the vertex exposure martingale, using the fact that exposing a new vertex affects the chromatic number by at most 1.

Comment: Thanks, Yuval! I finally got 1 now...It seems I still got trouble in applying the Azuma's inequality which seems to be a question how to estimate the vertices. I expect to have something like $P(|\chi(G|_S)-E(\chi(X(G|_S))|>\sqrt{n}a)\leq 2\exp\{-a^2/2\}$ ,where $n$ is the number of vertices.  Then I got confused, should I really use the vertex exposure? It seem I have no control on $n$.

Comment: Right. Perhaps you should expose one independent set at a time. Since the graph is 600-colorable, it can be decomposed into 600 independent sets.

Comment: Great!!I think I am almost there. For estimating the mean can not be too small, I tried to use $E \chi(G|_S)=\int_{0}^{600} P(\chi(G|_S)>t)dt$ which I can only show to be larger than 150. I think it might not be good enough. Any way to improve it?

Comment: It's your exercise and it is best if you did it on your own. That's the only way to learn anything.

Comment: thanks! I think I also ask too much...sorry about that. I finally see the mean can not be too low by looking back at (1).